# LINQ Intersect on inner collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of **Stores** (of type `ObservableCollection<Store>`) and the `Store` object has a property called **Features** ( of type `List<Feature>` ). and the `Feature` object has a **Name** property (of type `string`).

To recap, a list of Stores that has a list of Features

I have a second collection of **DesiredFeatures** (of type `List<string>` ).

I need to use LINQ to give me results of *only* the stores that have *all* the DesiredFeatures. So far, I've only been able to come up with a query that gives me an **OR** result instead of **AND**.

Here's what that looks like:

`var q = Stores.Where(s=> s.Features.Any(f=> DesiredFeatures.Contains(f.name)));`

I know `Intersect` can help, and here's how I've used it:

`var q = Stores.Where(s => s.Features.Intersect<Feature>(DesiredFeatures));`

This is where I'm stuck, Intersect wants a `Feature` object, what I need to intersect is on the Feature.Name.

The goal is to end up with an ObservableCollection where each Store has all of the DesiredFeatures.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to use LINQ to give me results of only the stores that have **all** the DesiredFeatures.

In other words, each desired feature must have a matching store feature.

I don't see how `Intersect` can help in this case. The direct translation of the above criteria to LINQ is like this:

```
var q = Stores.Where(s =>
    DesiredFeatures.All(df => s.Features.Any(f => f.Name == df))
);
```

A more efficient way could be to use a [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx) for performing the match:

```
var q = Stores.Where(s => 
    DesiredFeatures.GroupJoin(s.Features,
        df => df, sf => sf.Name, (df, sf) => sf.Any()
    ).All(match => match)
);
```

or [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx) to check for unmatched items:

```
var q = Stores.Where(s =>
    !DesiredFeatures.Except(s.Features.Select(sf => sf.Name)).Any()
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, GroupJoin was the perfect solution and did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You've almost done what you need. A small refine would be to swap `DesiredFeatures` and `s.Features`.

```
var q = Stores.Where(s => DesiredFeatures.All(df => s.Features.Contains(df)));
```

It means take only those stores where desired features are all contained in features of the store.

Comment: very close, but my `df` is a string, not a Feature. I guess I could refactor to make DesiredFeatures a List<Feature>, but that seems like a band-aid

Answer (score 1):

Going on your intersect idea, the only way I thought of making this work was by using `Select` to get the Store.Features (`List<Feature>`) as a list of Feature Names (`List<string>`) and intersect that with DesiredFeatures.

**Updated Answer:**

```
var q = Stores.Where(s => s.Features.Select(f => f.Name).Intersect(DesiredFeatures).Any());
```

or

```
var q = Stores.Where(s => DesiredFeatures.Intersect(s.Features.Select(f => f.Name)).Any());
```

**Old Answer** (if DesiredFeatures is a `List<Feature>`)**:**

```
var q = Stores.Where(s => s.Features.Select(f => f.Name).Intersect(DesiredFeatures.Select(df => df.Name)).Any());
```

Comment: Very close as well, but DesiredFeatures is a `List<string>`. If I change `DesiredFeatures.Select(df=>df)` I get the same result as my original attempt.

Comment: Oh, apologies. I didn't see that DesiredFeatures is a list of string. Is it a list of Feature Names or some other information? You should probably specify this in your question as well.

Comment: Yeah, I know it appears that way in my first query, but the f.name in the predicate comes from Features. I'm attempting to refactor to List<Feature> instead as it may be less complicated

Comment: I've updated my answer. One thing that's worth noting is that you need to call `Select` on the Store.Features so you intersect on a List<string>, the list of Feature Names.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you want your code to perform.

```
var q = Stores.Where(s=> s.Features.All(f=> DesiredFeatures.Contains(f.name)) && 
                         s.Features.Count() == DesiredFeatures.Count()); // Incude Distinct in the comparison if Features list is not unique
```

- Ensure that *every* Feature is DesiredFeature
- Store contains *all* Desired features.

*Code above assumes uniqueness in `Features` collection as well as `DesiredFeatures`, modify code as stated in comment line if this is not right*